Hilbert’s basis theorem never holds for non-unital Noetherian rings.
I am trying to show that Hilbert’s basis theorem never holds for non-unital Noetherian rings. The exercise outlines a proof, starting with taking $ S $, a commutative, not necessarily unital ring. Assume that $ S[X] $ is Noetherian. Then:
$(a)$ $S$ is Noetherian.
$(b)$ for any $s\in S,$ there exists an $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $sX^{n+1}$ is in the ideal $<s,sX,\ldots,sX^{n}>.$
$(c)$ For any finite set $\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_k\}\subset S$, there exists a $t\in S$ such that $s_i=ts_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,k.$ Deduce that $S$ is unital.
I managed to prove parts (a) and (b) myself, but I am struggling with part (c). Deducing that $ S $ is unital is not hard, but constructing $t$  is where I am stuck. I suspect the solution uses part (b) in a clever way, but I do not see it. Any hint would be appreciated.

How did you deduce that $S$ is unital without figuring out how to prove (c) from (b)?

Once you assume the first part of $c$ is true, you take a finite set of generators for $S$. This is possible since $S$ is Noetherian. Then we apply the first part of $c$ to this set of generators. The resulting $t$ acts like a unit on the generators, so it must also act like a unit on the entire ring. Thus, $S$ has a unit, namely $t.$

As a first step, we can use (b) to prove that for any element $s \in S$, we can find $t \in S$ such that $ts = s$. Indeed, we know from (b) that $sX^{n+1} \in \langle s,sX,\dots,sX^n \rangle$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, which means that we can find polynomials $p_0,\dots,p_n \in S[X]$ such that
\begin{equation*}
sX^{n+1} = p_0(X)s+p_1(X)sX+\dots+p_n(X)sX^n.
\end{equation*}
For these two polynomials to agree, they need to have the same coefficient of $X^{n+1}$. To this end, write
\begin{equation*}
p_k = \sum_i s_{k,i}X^i
\end{equation*}
and expand the right-hand side of the equation to find that the coefficients of $X^{n+1}$ are
\begin{equation*}
s = s_{0,n+1}s+s_{1,n}s+\dots+s_{n,1}s.
\end{equation*}
This implies that $ts = s$, where $t = s_{0,n+1}+s_{1,n}+\dots+s_{n,1}$.
The next step is to show that given two elements $s_1,s_2 \in S$ and their "associated units" $t_1,t_2$, we can find a "common unit" for both $s_1$ and $s_2$. Indeed, simply notice that
\begin{equation*}
(t_1+t_2-t_1t_2)s_1 = s_1 \quad\text{and}\quad (t_1+t_2-t_1t_2)s_2 = s_2.
\end{equation*}
The same argument proves that given a unit $t_I$ for an ideal $I$ (i.e. an element $t_I$ such that $t_Ix = x$ for all $x \in I$) and a unit $t$ for an element $s$, then $t_I+t-t_It$ is a unit for $I+\langle s \rangle$. Using this, we can prove the first part of (c) by induction on $k$. As you commented above, this is enough to prove that $S$ is unital since it is finitely generated.

Thank you, it was exactly this kind of trick I was looking for.
